# Calling STL vector's push_back in a mixed mode assembly via C# in a new managed thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, stl, c++-cli

I'm writing a WPF application that does its core magic in native C++, nicely wrapped by C++/CLI classes within a mixed mode assembly.

Within a method of a C++/CLI wrapper class, I'm creating a new instance of a vector and pushing back a value:

```
void Wrapper::CallVectorPushBack()
{
    vector<int> foo;
    foo.push_back(1);
}
```

This works fine when running the code in the main thread of the application.

Now let's try calling the code above in a new managed thread from C#:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Wrapper.CallVectorPushBack(); });
```

When creating a new thread for executing the code above, the first push_back call on the vector instance locks the thread. The new thread gets stuck and Visual Studio displays _MtxLock as address in the Threads window.

What is neccessary to make the code run?

Thank you in advance!

Cheers!

Comment: I doubt this is the reason, as 'foo' is just a local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tracked down the problem:

The C++/CLI wrapper DLL implements a DllMain method that reads registry keys with the CRegistry library (https://code.google.com/p/cregistry/). Reading a non-existing registry key within a try catch block f*cks up the above mentioned application's threading capabilities...